# boost:enable_if to define a dedicated method in a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, boost, enable-if

I would like to have a custom method - I will call MyMethod - in a templated class - I will call Foo - ONLY when Foo has been instanciated with certain template parameters types (eg. when A is int and B is string), otherwise, I don't want MyMethod to exist at all on any other possible Foo instance.

Is that possible ?

Example:

```
template<class A, class B>
class Foo
{
    string MyMethod(whatever...);
}
```

boost:enable_if can help there ?

Thanks!!

Comment: There's also `std::enable_if` if you are using C++11.  You should look into SFINAE.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Answer (score 0):

What you really want here is to specialize your template. In your example, you would write:

```
template<>
class Foo<int, string>
{
    string MyMethod(whatever...); 
};
```

you can also use enable_if:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo
{
    typename boost::enable_if<
            boost::mpl::and_<
                boost::mpl::is_same<A, int>,
                boost::mpl::is_same<B, string>
            >,
            string>::type MyMethod(whatever...){}
};
```

if there are no overloads, you can also use static_assert:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo
{
    string MyMethod(whatever...)
    {
         static_assert(your condition here, "must validate condition");
         // method implementation follows
    }
};
```

this will produce a compile error when you try to invoke MyMethod and the  condition is not set.

Comment: template specialization works, but I would have to duplicate any other - standard - Foo method.

Comment: @codeJack Then you can always use the second method. However, SFINAE is more important for overload resolution. If there are no overloads, you can just use static_assert and you can provide a better error message.

Comment: interesting, how would you use static assert in my example ?